# Read specific object data from json

Tags: c#, json

I want to get specific object data from json  from url the following code give me. i need the second object 'EmailAddressSuffices'
 [image]

```
    WebRequest request = WebRequest.Create(
      "https://atea-dev.accesscontrol.windows.net/v2/metadata/IdentityProviders.js?protocol=wsfederation&realm=https%3a%2f%2flocalhost%3a44300%2fAccount%2fLoginCallback%2f&reply_to=https%3a%2f%2flocalhost%3a44300%2fAccount%2fLoginCallback%2f&context=&request_id=&version=1.0&callback=");
    request.Credentials = CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials;
    WebResponse response = request.GetResponse();
    Stream dataStream = response.GetResponseStream();
    StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(dataStream);
    string responseFromServer = reader.ReadToEnd();
```

Comment: have you try to deserialize the json into c# object?

Comment: no, i am not try yet

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using [JSON.Net](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json) you can deserialize the JSON response easily:

**Solution 1**

1. Create a class to map your JSON into:

```
public class ResponseObject
{

    [JsonProperty("Name")]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("LoginUrl")]
    public string LoginUrl { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("LogoutUrl")]
    public string LogoutUrl { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("ImageUrl")]
    public string ImageUrl { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("EmailAddressSuffixes")]
    public IList<string> EmailAddressSuffixes { get; set; }
}
```

2. Deserialize your JSON using `JsonConvert.Deserialize<ResponseObject>()`

```
var myresponse = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<ResponseObject>>(responseFromServer);
string email = myresponse[1].EmailAddressSuffixes[0];
```

**Solution 2**

If you don't want to bother with derializing the entire thing then you can do this:

```
JArray array = JArray.Parse(responseFromServer);
string q = array[1]["EmailAddressSuffixes"][0].ToString();
```

But you should make sure that your object has the right format (and the right number of items in the array.